# Is there a way to print source code info and sql query in django logs?

Tags: django, logging, django-database

I am logging db information to a file, but what I would really like to do is see the code that produces each query, or at least the file/line number.

Is there a way to do this? Using filename/funcName/etc (see http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) only log the lower level files/functions (i.e. 'execute' in 'utils.py', instead of my code).

Answer (score 0):

The SQLCompiler is located at `django.db.models.sql.compiler`

You can poke around in there. Some of what is there gets delegated to the other helper files in the sql folder and some others get further delegated to the base file in the respective backend.

You could probably attempt to log the variables as they come through those particular points.

I'm curious though, why?

Comment: Because I'd like to know which pieces of code are producing which queries. I can guess, but it'd be nice to just have it printed out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Django toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/) which is can give you sql queries for a page with backtrace  and timings too.

Comment: That would normally be exactly what I need but I'm running a taskserver and Django toolbar doesn't give me information on the taskserver.